# How to read a dbf/dbt file directly?

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing, dbase

Does anyone know how to read the data directly from a dBase .DBF/.DBT file set?

Details:

I am trying to write a parser according to the dBase specs for dbf/dbt files.

The DBF file is relatively simple with the value in a MEMO field being the sequential block number that the data for that field supposedly starts at in the dbt file.

The DBT file isn't defined deeply in the specs.  When I parse the DBT file (which according to the specs is made of sequential blocks[sized 512 bytes each] with block 0 being a header block), I see extra byte data interspersed between the record data (some look like "garbage" binary data, some look like other table names in the db).  With some of the extra data containing letters/numbers, it makes trying to read just the record data of the block near impossible.  There is no clear-cut definition of these strange data in the specs that I can see.  I assume it may be some kind of header data, but it does not seem to have a fixed byte width or even appearing at the same location for each block.

Also the sequential block number in the DBF file's Memo field does not always seem to line up with the actual data.  I.e. record 2 in the dbf says it starts at block 2, but actually in the dbt file it starts at block 6.

Does anyone know more information about the structure of the DBT file?  Maybe something that I'm missing?

Code example (VB.Net):

```
' Holds information about data in the header .dbf file.
Public Class HeaderFileClass
    Public Property AccountNo As String     ' 6 bytes
    Public Property BlockNumber As String   '10 bytes
    Public Property DateInfo As String      '8 bytes
    Public Property EditBy As String        '3 bytes
    Public Sub New()
        AccountNo = String.Empty
        BlockNumber = String.Empty
        DateInfo = String.Empty
        EditBy = String.Empty
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(newAcctNo As String, newBlockNo As String, newDateInf As String, newEditBy As String)
        AccountNo = newAcctNo
        BlockNumber = newBlockNo
        DateInfo = newDateInf
        EditBy = newEditBy
    End Sub
End Class
' Strips a byte array of anything but alpha-numerics, space, or line feed.
Private Function CleanBytes(ByRef bytes As Byte()) As Byte()
    Dim newBytes As Byte()
    Dim BLOCKSIZE As Integer = 512
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    Dim strOut As String = String.Empty
    ReDim newBytes(BLOCKSIZE)
    newBytes.Initialize()
    For Each i As Byte In bytes
        Dim intVal As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(i)
        If (intVal >= 32 And intVal <= 126) Or intVal = 10 Then
            newBytes(j) = i
            j += 1
        End If
    Next
    Return newBytes
End Function
Private Sub ParseFile()
    Dim fileName As String = "C:\dbbackup\Schalls\Schalls_CleanLegacy\Schall_Clean_DATA\PATNOTES"       ' data location.
    Dim BLOCKSIZE As Integer = 512                  ' Default block size.
    Dim bytes As Byte() = Nothing                   ' bytes to be read from dbt file.
    Dim buffer As Char()                            ' buffer to use for reading dbf file.
    Dim hList As New List(Of HeaderFileClass)       ' DBF header data storage.
    Dim lstData As New List(Of Byte())              ' DBT block data storage.
    ReDim buffer(28)                                ' Set size of buffer array.

    'header file load
    Using inFile As New StreamReader(File.Open(fileName & ".DBF", FileMode.Open))
        ' read DBF header lines.
        inFile.ReadLine()
        inFile.ReadLine()

        ' read DBF data.
        While inFile.Read(buffer, 0, 28) > 0
            Dim strBuf As New String(buffer)
            Dim acctNo As String = strBuf.Substring(0, 7)
            Dim blockNo As String = strBuf.Substring(7, 10).Trim
            Dim dateInfo As String = strBuf.Substring(17, 8)
            Dim editBy As String = strBuf.Substring(25, 3)
            hList.Add(New HeaderFileClass(acctNo, blockNo, dateInfo, editBy))
        End While
    End Using


    'memo file load
    Using inFile As New BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName & ".DBT", FileMode.Open))
        ' read data sequentially by blocksize.
        Do
            bytes = inFile.ReadBytes(BLOCKSIZE)
            If bytes.Length > 0 Then
                lstData.Add(bytes)
            End If
        Loop While bytes.Length > 0
    End Using

    If hList.Count > 2 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To hList.Count - 2
            Dim h As HeaderFileClass = hList(i)             ' get data for the current record from the header file data. (contains block number to start)
            Dim h2 As HeaderFileClass = hList(i + 1)        ' get the next data for the current record. (contains next starting block number)
            Dim intFrom As Integer = CInt(h.BlockNumber)    ' starting block number.
            Dim intTo As Integer = CInt(h2.BlockNumber)     ' next record's starting block number.
            Dim sbStr As New System.Text.StringBuilder      ' output string.

            ' read the bytes, ensure they are text data, 
            For j As Integer = intFrom To intTo - 1
                sbStr.Append(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(CleanBytes(lstData(j))))
            Next
            Debug.Print(sbStr.ToString)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you written any code? Please post the relevant code with the issue or doubt you have.

Comment: I will post the code as soon as I get to my work computer in about 30 minutes.

Comment: I hope you have read this before posting question: http://www.dbase.com/Knowledgebase/INT/db7_file_fmt.htm

Comment: I486, I've been all over Google for a number of weeks on this.  Kind of doing this question as a last hope.  And the page you referenced is one of the sources I've been to before that I'm talking about that doesn't have further definition.  It mentions the Sequential block numbers after header, but does not account for this bunk binary data I'm seeing, nor the mismatch in the dbf Block number reference.

Comment: There was a library called Codebase by Sequiter Software. I am not sure it was available as souce code but it works with dBase files and I hope it can help you.

Comment: I486, ok I'll look for it.  Thanks.

Comment: Note that `Dim newBytes(BLOCKSIZE) As Byte` allocates BLOCKSIZE+1 elements (because the array index starts at 0) - you want `Dim newBytes(BLOCKSIZE - 1) As Byte`. (There's no need for a separate REDIM to set the size.) And you should be declaring and setting BLOCKSIZE in only one place, to make it easy to change and difficult to set wrongly.

Comment: You are using `StreamReader.ReadLine` to read a binary file with a defined structure?  That is asking for trouble.  You say that you have seen the file format specification mentioned by the others,  so you should be able to read the specified byte patterns directly and then apply the proper encoding to convert the bytes to a string if that is what they are suppoed to represent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OLEDB, for example:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Private FileName As String = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Customer.dbf")
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If IO.File.Exists(FileName) Then
            Dim Builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With
                {
                    .DataSource = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName),
                    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
                }
            Builder.Add("Extended Properties", "dBase III")
            Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString}
                Using cmd As New OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " & IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName)
                    cn.Open()
                    Dim dt As New DataTable
                    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```